# Add Kubernetes scrape target to Prometheus instance that is NOT in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, target

I run [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) locally as http://localhost:9090/targets with

```
docker run --name prometheus -d -p 127.0.0.1:9090:9090 prom/prometheus
```

and want to connect it to several Kubernetes (cluster) instances we have.
See that scraping works, try [Grafana dashboards](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards) etc.

And then I'll do the same on dedicated server that will be specially for monitoring.
However all googling gives me all different ways to configure prometheus that is already within one Kubernetes instance, and no way to read metrics from external Kubernetes.

**How to add Kubernetes scrape target to Prometheus instance that is NOT in Kubernetes?**

---

I have read [Where Kubernetes metrics come from](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-performance-metrics/#where-kubernetes-metrics-come-from) and checked that my (first) Kubernetes cluster has the **Metrics Server**.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep metrics-server
```

There is definitely no sense to add Prometheus instance into every Kubernetes (cluster) instance. One Prometheus must be able to read metrics from many Kubernetes clusters and every node within them.

P.S. Some [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132281/monitor-kubernetes-cluster-from-other-kubernetes-cluster-with-prometheus) has answer to install Prometheus in every Kubernetes and then use federation, that is just opposite from what I am looking for.

P.P.S. It is also strange for me, why Kubernetes and Prometheus that are #1 and #2 projects from Cloud Native Foundation don't have simple "add Kubernetes target in Prometheus" button or simple step.

Comment: Is your problem now resolved?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, deploying a Prometheus instance in each cluster is a more simple and clean way than organizing external access. The main problem is that the targets discovered with `kubernetes_sd_configs` are cluster-internal DNS-names and IP-addresses (or at least, it is so in my AWS EKS cluster). To resolve and reach these, you have to be inside the cluster.

This problem can be resolved by using a proxy and so the configuration below uses API-server's proxy endpoint to reach targets. I'm not sure about its performance in large clusters, but in such case it is well-worth to deploy an internal Prometheus instance.

#### External access through API-server proxy

Things you need (for each cluster):

1. API-server CA certificate for HTTPS to work (see below how to get it).
2. Service account token with appropriate permissions (depends on your needs).

Assuming you already have these, here is an example Prometheus configuration:

```yaml
- job_name: 'kubelet-cadvisor'
  scheme: https

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
    api_server: https://api-server.example.com

    # TLS and auth settings to perform service discovery
    authorization:
      credentials_file: /kube/token  # the file with your service account token
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /kube/CA.crt  # the file with the CA certificate

  # The same as above but for actual scrape request.
  # We're going to send scrape requests back to the API-server
  # so the credentials are the same.
  bearer_token_file: /kube/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /kube/CA.crt

  relabel_configs:
  # This is just to drop this long __meta_kubernetes_node_label_ prefix
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)

  # By default Prometheus goes to /metrics endpoint.
  # This relabeling changes it to /api/v1/nodes/[kubernetes_io_hostname]/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
  - source_labels: [kubernetes_io_hostname]
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
    target_label: __metrics_path__

  # This relabeling defines that Prometheus should connect to the
  # API-server instead of the actual instance. Together with the relabeling
  # from above this will make the scrape request proxied to the node kubelet.
  - replacement: api-server.example.com
    target_label: __address__
```

The above is tailored for scraping `role: node`. To make it working with other roles, you've got to change `__metrics_path__` label. The ["Manually constructing apiserver proxy URLs"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls) article can help constructing the path.

#### How to get API-server CA certificate

There are several ways to get it but getting it from `kubeconfig` appears to me as the simplest:

```sh
❯ kubectl config view --raw
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:                      # you need this ⤋ long value 
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJ...
    server: https://api-server.example.com
  name: default
...
```

The certificate in `kubeconfig` is base64-encoded so you have to decode it before it can be used:

```sh
echo LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJ... | base64 -d > CA.crt
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, you want to monitor kubernetes cluster where prometheus is not installed on remote kubernetes cluster.

> I monitor many different kubernetes cluster from one prometheus which
> is installed on a standalone server.

***You can do this by generating a token on the kubernetes server using a service account which has proper permission to access the kubernetes api.***

**Kubernetes-api:**

Following are the details required to configure prometheus scrape job.

1. Create a service account which has permissions to read and watch the
   pods.
2. Generate token from the service account.
3. Create scrape job as following.

```
- job_name: kubernetes
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
    api_server: https://kubernetes-cluster-api.com
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
      bearer_token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  bearer_token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  relabel_configs:
  - separator: ;
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    replacement: $1
    action: labelmap
```

I have explained the same in detail in the article
"Monitor remote kubernetes cluster using prometheus".
https://amjadhussain3751.medium.com/monitor-remote-kubernetes-cluster-using-prometheus-a3781b041745

Comment: I had gone through the link.  I created ServiceAccount, installed Prometheus and created scrape.  Should I install cAdvisor as well on Master node to collect metrics ?  Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

There are many agents capable of saving metrics collected in k8s to remote Prometheus server outside the cluster, example Prometheus itself now support [agent mode](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/11/16/agent/#prometheus-agent-mode), exporter from [Opentelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#exporters), or using [managed Prometheus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-onboard-ingest-metrics-OpenTelemetry.html) etc.

Comment: See Architecture overview on https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus and understand that Prometheus can do *pulling*, so no need to install any agent that will do *pushing*.  And again this answer suggest to install something, while https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/ says that Kubernetes (direct)ly "exposes metrics in the Prometheus format, so no separate exporters are needed". While there may be value in this suggestion, it cannot be the accepted answer.

Comment: Also Prometheus agent is new experimental feature from v2.32.0, it is not how Prometheus was supposed to be used originally.

Comment: Try read from the top, the author has explained well with justifications. One can wait for Prometheus agent mode to go GA, or there are many agents software out there already doing this anyway. Expose in Prometheus format does not means metrics automatically save to Prometheus server. It's up to you if you want to expose ALL possible /metrics endpoints every now and then, not to mention those private clusters... and continue pulling from outside.